# Multiple addresses checkout setting wrong shipping rate

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, shipping

Multiple addresses **checkout** setting wrong **shipping rate** in the **overview (review my order) page**. In this particular case I am sending 3 items to one address and 1 item to another address.

this **image** shows my **3 items shipping** to **1 US address**. I previously selected the $15.00 **flat rate shipping**. The total amount is correct but the **shipping amount** displayed is wrong. It should be $15.00

[image]

Is this a known magento bug? am I setting something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get resolved?